# Proper count indicator in a BusinessObjects Universe?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

If, given a person, location and date dimension I have the following factless fact table (only for counting purpose).

```
personId ; locationId ; dateId
   1   ;     1    ;   20160501
   1   ;     1    ;   20160503
   2   ;     2    ;   20160503
   3   ;     2    ;   20160502
```

I want to have the number of distinct people so I decided to use this indicator :
**Indicator's parameters :**
Select : `count(distinct personId)`
Function (in the second tab) : Sum

And I want to have in the same report the distinct count of personId per location in one table and per date in another table.
This means I'll have two different countings, one per table, but BO will use only one SQL request because both are in the same Webi document.

**The problem:**
The SQL request generated by BO will result in the following :

```
locationId ; dateId      ; count(distinct personId)
     1     ;   20160501  ;   1
     1     ;   20160503  ;   1
     2     ;   20160503  ;   1
     2     ;   20160502  ;   1
```

But if, as I said, I want the number of people by location on one side and by date on the other side things start to get messy.
Apparently, because of the "Function : Sum" of my indicator, BO will use  sums of the finer grained count distinct result above instead of making a proper count distinct.

Therefore I'll have these results :

```
locationId ; count(distinct personId)
     1     ;      2
     2     ;      1
     2     ;      1
```

Instead of having 1 distinct person for location 1.
And

```
dateId    ; count(distinct personId)
20160501  ;   1
20160503  ;   2
20160502  ;   1
```

Instead of having on distinct person for date 20160503.

**Question**
Is there another way to make a proper Count distinct *indicator* in a BusinessObjects Universe ?
I don't mean using `=Count([personId],Distinct)` in my Webi report, which works, but really having an indicator that will do the job without summing things randomly.
I tried an indicator with : 
Select : `personId`
Function (from the second tab) : `Count`
But it doesn't result in a proper count distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aggregations like this, where the client tool (WebI in this case) cannot perform the re-aggregation itself whenever the set of dimensions change, you should use the projection function *delegated* in your universe.

Taken from the *Information Design Tool User Guide*:

> If the projection function is *Sum*, the measure will be summed locally in the report. If the projection function is *Delegated*, the projection function requests that the aggregation be done in the database instead of aggregating locally.

When you change the dimensions in you report, you'll notice that the value of for the measure will be replaced by `#TOREFRESH`. This means that WebI needs to ask the back-end (the RDBMS in this case) to recalculate and re-aggregate the measure according to the new set of dimensions.

Averages are another type of aggregation that require the projection function to be set to *Delegated* in order to assure a correct calculation.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. I'm new to BO so your precision about averages will certainly avoid me some mistakes in the future too.